# Retrieve Parse data outside the block

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

```
    -(void) GetParseData
{
     self.ParseArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


  PFQuery *RetreiveQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EventInfo"];

    [RetreiveQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects,NSError *error)
    {
        if(!error)
        {

            self.ParseArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];


            NSLog(@" Inside Objects Array Retreived %lu",[self.ParseArray count]);

        }
   }];
   NSLog(@" Outside Objects Array Retreived %lu",[self.ParseArray count]);

}
```

I am trying to retrieve the objects data from parse into the array ParseArray. But when I try to use it outside the block, it doesn't have any data. How can I use the parse data outside the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can't because block code is run after your statement

```
NSLog(@" Outside Objects Array Retreived %lu",[self.ParseArray count]);
```

because it is block code . So you have to create one block with return parameter as an `array` to get values.

so what you have to do is.

**Create one callback:**

in .h (or .m file).

```
typedef void (^ParseArrayCallback)(NSMutableArray *array);
```

**Add that callback as parameter in your method:**

```
-(void) GetParseData:(ParseArrayCallback)parseArrayCallback{

 self.ParseArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];


  PFQuery *RetreiveQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"EventInfo"];

    [RetreiveQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects,NSError *error)
    {
        if(!error)
        {

            self.ParseArray= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:objects];

          if(parseArrayCallback) {
                        parseArrayCallback(self.ParseArray);
               }
            NSLog(@" Inside Objects Array Retreived %lu",[self.ParseArray count]);

        }
   }];

    }
```

**Get your result in block :**

```
[self GetParseData:^(NSMutableArray *array){
NSLog(@" Outside Objects Array Retreived %lu",[array count]);
}];
```

Hope it will help you.